# Show that if Span$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$=$\mathbb{R}^3$ then $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Show that if Span$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$=$\mathbb{R}^3$ then $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly independent.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Assume that Span$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$=$\mathbb{R}^3$ and assume to the contrary that the $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly dependent. It follows $$ c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=\vec{0} \text{ if at least one $c_i\neq0$ for $i=1,2, \text{ or } 3$}$$ 
It follows that at least one vector is a linear combination of the other two vectors. This means that the span reduces to a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ which is a contradiction.

I feel that this proof lacks some generalization or I could add more detailed steps where I have "it follows that atleast one vector..." making the proof more formal.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean "$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=\vec{0} \text{ where at least one }c_i\neq 0\text{ for } i=1,2, \text{ or } 3$"

Comment: All this uses the fact  that $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be spanned by $2$ vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of symmetry it is enough to consider the case when $c_1\ne 0$ (in the definition of linear independence it is assumed that not all scalars are zero). Then $v_1=-\dfrac{c_2}{c_1}v_2-\dfrac{c_3}{c_1}v_3$ which proves the claim you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you study this already but if this question was given to me I would say as you said with a little note to make it clearer: if, let's say, $v_1$ could be created by the other 2, let's say, $v_1=k_1v_2+k_2v_2$ than the span of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ was equal to the span of $v_2,v_3$ and then I would add the proof that if the span of $v_1,v_2,\cdots ,v_n$ is $ℝ^k$ then $n\ge k$.